# Xamarin iOS start background download when the data is turned on

Tags: c#, ios, swift, xamarin.ios

I have an application which should be able to download some contents when user turns on the data in the phone. The blogs and articles which i came across mention that background can be started when the user exists the application and this can be achieved using background transfer service.

However, i wanted to initiate the background download service whenever user enables data (internet) on their iOS device. I am looking for any possibility of registering any possible services that detects whenever the user enables data and start the download service in background, even if the user has not opened the application.

Please let me know if there are any possibility of this achieving this in iOS or Xamarin.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to do something in background ,you have to open the application first and keep it in background then use background transfer service, it is impossible to start downloading service when the app is closed .

Comment: Thanks for the info. Also, what will happen if the app has been killed by the user (using app drawer), will the background transfer service continue or get killed?

Comment: It would be killed.